# using mergeMap in forkJoin to get observables depending one on the other

Tags: angular, rxjs, fork-join, mergemap

I have a combination of several async request I need to complete together (doing it with forkJoin) - when doing so, I initiate an object:

```typescript
    export class fullData
    {
        AProp  : any;
        BProp  : any;
        CProp  : any;
    }
    const fullDataObservable : fullData = forkJoin(
    {
        AProp : this.myFirstSrv.getAProp(), 
        BProp : this.mySecondsSrv.getBProp(),
        CProp : this.myThirdSrv.getCProp()
    });
    return fullDataObservable;
```

So far - so good. Now - I have **3 new properties** in this object:

```typescript
    export class fullData
    {
        AProp  : any;
        BProp  : any;
        CProp  : any;
        prop1 : any;
        prop2 : any;
        prop3 : any;
        
    }
```

the **first** of then (**prop1**) depend on the CProp value (or this.myThirdSrv.getCProp()) as a parameter, when doing a get request, the **second (prop2)** is a simple manipulation of the **first** one, and the third one (**prop3**) is also depending on the **second** as a parameter in a get request. I've tried using a mergeMap, but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong ?:

```typescript
    gatherAllRelevantData() : any
      {
        //this.myService.getProp1() return observable after get request 
        this.myService.getProp1().pipe
        (
          mergeMap((prop1Value : any[]) => 
          {
            //this.myService.getResultAfterSimpleManipulation return object, not observable
            let prop2Values : any[] = this.myService.getResultAfterSimpleManipulation(prop1Value);
            //the this.getProp3Value return observable aftet get request
            return this.getProp3Value(prop2Value).pipe(
              map(prop3Values => 
                {
                  return { prop1 : prop1Value, prop2 : prop2Values, prop3 : prop3Values };
                })
            )
          }
      ));
    }
```

This should all done in a resolve function and should initiate the fullData object, by getting data from the this.gatherAllRelevantData (not happening) and without unneeded execution of the this.gatherAllRelevantData:

```typescript
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> 
    {
      const fullDataObservable = forkJoin(
      {
        AProp : this.myFirstSrv.getAProp(), 
        BProp : this.mySecondsSrv.getBProp(),
        CProp : this.myThirdSrv.getCProp(),
        prop1 : this.gatherAllRelevantData().map(item => items.prop1),
        prop1 : this.gatherAllRelevantData().map(item => items.prop1),
        prop1 : this.gatherAllRelevantData().map(item => items.prop1)
    });
    return fullDataObservable; 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. If the class `fullData` is only used to hold the member variables, you could use an interface instead.
2. Based on the conditions you've mentioned you could use RxJS `switchMap` (or `mergeMap`) operator along with the `map` operator to get the object of your requirement.

Try the following

```js
export interface fullData {
  AProp: any;
  BProp: any;
  CProp: any;
  prop1: any;
  prop2: any;
  prop3: any;
}

const fullDataObservable: Observable<fullData> = forkJoin({ // <-- it's of type `Observable<fullData>`, not `fullData`
  AProp: this.myFirstSrv.getAProp(), 
  BProp: this.mySecondsSrv.getBProp(),
  CProp: this.myThirdSrv.getCProp()
}).pipe(
  switchMap(data =>
    this.someService.getProp1(data.CProp).pipe( // <-- get `prop1` that depend on `data.CProp`
      map(prop1 => ({
        AProp: data.AProp,
        BProp: data.BProp,
        CProp: data.CProp,
        prop1: prop1,
        prop2: this.simpleManipulate(prop1) // <-- get `prop2` that depend on `prop1`
      }))
    )
  ),
  switchMap(data =>
    this.someService.getProp3(data.prop2).pipe( // <-- get `prop3` that depend on `data.prop2`
      map(prop3 => ({
        AProp: data.AProp,
        BProp: data.BProp,
        CProp: data.CProp,
        prop1: data.prop1,
        prop2: data.prop2,
        prop3: data.prop3
      }))
    )
  )
)

return fullDataObservable;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem by solving one property at a time then combining everything at the end.

```typescript
  AProp = this.myFirstSrv.getAProp();
  BProp = this.mySecondSrv.getBProp();
  CProp = this.myThirdSrv.getCProp();
  prop1 = this.CProp.pipe(
    mergeMap(CProp => this.propsSrv.getProp1(CProp))
  )
  prop2 = this.AProp.pipe(
    map(AProp => this.propsSrv.getProp2(AProp))
  )
  prop3 = this.BProp.pipe(
    mergeMap(BProp => this.propsSrv.getProp3(BProp))
  )

  fullData$ = forkJoin({
    AProp: this.AProp,
    BProp: this.BProp,
    CProp: this.CProp,
    prop1: this.prop1,
    prop2: this.prop2,
    prop3: this.prop3,
  })
```

[See link to a stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k1copg)